# How to create a perfect square with an aspect ratio of 1:1 while using percentage (%)

Tags: html, css, height, width, aspect-ratio

**My goal is to have a div that has an aspect ratio of 1:1 on any screen size.**

In order to achieve that, I gave my div a width of 50% and height of 50%. I thought by giving it a width of 50% and height of 50% that I would be able to get a perfect square with an aspect ratio of 1:1.

Well, I was wrong...

The div respects the width of 50% that I gave it, for example on a screen size of 200px it takes a width of 100px and on a screen size of 500px it takes a width of 250px, **50% width like I specified.**

BUT the height doesn't respect the height of 50% that I gave it...
^^^Again, I assumed that if I gave it a width and height of 50% that the height would be the same as the width and that the div would be a perfect square.

How do I achieve my goal?
How do I make my div become a perfect square with an aspect ratio of 1:1 while using percentage width and height?

Comment: width and height don't have the same reference so making both 50% doesn't mean they will be equal

Comment: yes I realized that, but how would I achieve it?